# If we have an Auditorium, should we have Concerts?

Tags: discussion, chat, event

I recently became aware that we have at least 2 regular chatrooms. The Practice Room for general music p&p chitchat. And The Auditorium for performance critique.

Now, I think this is great in its own right. But it's also great because it's similar to an idea I posted to area 51 for a Master Class site for performance critiques. So it's like I thought of it, too.

But the real story is it keeps getting frozen for inactivity. So, we need to post something at least every 15 days to keepalive the chat room.

So, how about ***Concerts***? And/Or ***Recitals*** And/Or "***Open Mic Nite?***" And/Or ***Somebody else's great idea for a thing***?

Answer with a kind of event or thing (and a rough timetable, like "every Tuesday 12pm UTC for X hours" or "First Friday of the month", etc.) or say "Don't do this" if you don't like this idea at all.

Comment: Really would like to see The Auditorium take off. To these ideas specifically, for several years I participated in groups that took turns meeting at each others homes, roughly monthly, and playing whatever we happened to be working on at the time. One group was for advanced pianists, one for less advanced pianists, but both were fundamentally to encourage each other and worked wonders for me. There was clear growth in the other pianists as well, particularly in the "less advanced" group. I would at least seriously consider participating in similar events here.

Comment: If this gets traction, room owners can also create [chat events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295936/241919) as a reminder.

Comment: Kind of a tangent-idea, but: Plenty of us here like to ramble on philosophically on abstruse music topics (or maybe that's just me) that make poor SE questions or answers, like "Should I switch teachers" or "What is ethnomusicology and what is not?" We could have "chat party" sessions where we throw out a topic and go for it. Maybe, to keep it interesting, we could even select for serious conversation some of the most egregious closed questions ("Was Paganini the Joe Satriani of his day, or the Edge?")....

Comment: It’s a great idea, but if your goal is simply to keep the chat room from freezing, set up [Generic Bot](https://stackapps.com/questions/7337/generic-bot-a-moderation-chatbot) to do that for you.

Answer (score 5):

I propose that the 1st and 3rd Wednesday of the month (of March 2022 to begin with) shall be an **Open Mic Nite** in the Auditorium. At or about 12:00UTC on Tuesday an auxiliary chatroom will be opened to accept submissions until 12:00UTC on Wednesday after which I shall compile the submissions into a single playlist and post it to the Auditorium. Then the audience may discuss ad libitum.

Simpler procedure thanks to Aaron: just use the regular chatroom and prefix "Open Mic:" if submitting a link. The start and end times will also be posted in the chatroom (and possibly other places but the "official" start and stop will be in the chatroom).